# How to set time on a Date object to be zero (00/00/00)

Tags: java, date, time

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(0);
```

This sets it to the deafult value. How do I set it to zero?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?  I mean, you might as well ask how to set the date to Novtober eleventyfirst; there is no such date as Novtober eleventyfirst, and similarly, there is no such date as 0/0/0, so trying to get the runtime to represent that date seems like an exercise in futility. Presumably you have some reason you want to do this strange thing; if you can explain the reason, perhaps someone can show you a better way to do it.

Comment: I compare a system date (From our internal system) with a date that is given in the file.

Comment: How you try to compare your date ? Maybe there's a better way to do that ?

Comment: Maybe you want to display 00/00/00 when the two dates are equal?!

Answer (score 11):

You can zero-out what value you want using the set method. For example:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Comment: This would keep the month, day, and year as the current month day and year

Comment: I think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: The question is "How to set time on a Date object to be zero". Did I misunderstand?

Comment: I want the date to be zero so that when I do a DateFormat, I would get something like 00/00/00 (MM/dd/yy). Thanks.

Comment: If this is just for formatting purposes of display (and since Date can't represent very well the BigBang) you could use null for the date and display 00/00/00 as default when that is null. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

`(00/00/00)` is not a valid date; the API will not produce this value.

Comment: You should use a valid date in your examples.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably be aware of what `setTimeInMillis()` expects:

> `public void setTimeInMillis(long millis)`
>
> Sets this Calendar's current time from the given long value.
>
> Parameters:
>   `millis` - the new time in UTC milliseconds from the epoch.

The epoch is defined as:

> An instant in time can be represented by a millisecond value that is an offset from the Epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT (Gregorian).